# Updating solution level nuget packages in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to figure out a) if I'm going about this in the right way and b) how to update a solution level nuget package.

The core problem is that when a package is installed at the solution level (rather than in any particular project) and you try to update it, it doesn't remove the old reference. It just adds a new package reference, and imports both version. Which typically means (what with how powershell modules work) that the earlier powershell modules override the newer ones.

So what I have to do is uninstall the package and re-install it, which grabs the newer version. Seems inefficient.

Also, I can't seem to install or uninstall a solution level package from console. I have to do it with the Manage Nuget Packages utility, which I hate to use.

Here is some background on what I'm doing, if it helps:

I've set up a system at our company of using solution level nuget packages to add custom powershell script modules to the solution, as well as some more generalized scripted solutions I've written (like deleting TFS work items or changing a project name on the file system as well as within code).

So one project might have the DataServiceUtilities package and another would have the FrontEndUtilities package.

So, how can I update these packages without it adding two references? And can solution level operations be done in the Package Manager Console, which always defaults to targeting a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that some of this comes from bugs in the Package Manager GUI tools, and Nuget in general

The Package Manager GUI tool doesn't handle updates properly for solution level packages. But if you run Update-Package from the package manager console it will correctly uninstall/re-install the solution-level package.

As for installing from command line, if a package has only a tools folder and no dependencies you can run install from command line and it sill install in the solution and ignore the default project.

However, as of now (Nuget 2.8) Nuget has a bug in it that causes it to treat solution-level packages with dependencies on other solution-level packages as project-level packages. It's apparently been in for about a year, and they claim it will be fixed in VS 2015. You can see the bug here: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3642

What this means is you cannot currently create a solution-level package with ANY dependencies. Please note that this is legal according to the documentation. Hopefully it will be fixed next year.

*Update

Just a quick update. It appears that in VS 2015 they have deprecated (or, more accurately, removed) solution level/tools only packages. After some out outcry they also decided to re-implement them in a future version, but it may be awhile before they do so.

Progress on re-implementing the feature can be found here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1521

Discussion on how to work around the missing feature can be found here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522